# Disable automatic including of style sheets within a SiteFinity theme

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, themes, sitefinity

I'm working on integrating an HTML template slice into a SiteFinity theme and am wondering if there is a way to disable the automatic inclusion of the style sheets. I would prefer to manual include them from the MasterPage, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style sheets that are automatically included in Sitefinity are the CSS files that sit inside the ~/App_Themes/*ThemeName* directory.  This is an [ASP.NET feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx), not something specific to Sitefinity.

To remove this behavior, simply remove all the files from the ~/App_Themes/*ThemeName* directory.  However, do not remove the directory itself though.